# avoid outer element wrap in lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> html.tostring(html.fromstring('<div>1</div><div>2</div>'))
'<div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>'   # I dont want to outer <div>
>>> html.tostring(html.fromstring('I am pure text'))
'<p>I am pure text</p>'  # I dont need the extra <p>
```

How to avoid the outer `<div>` and `<p>` in lxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`lxml` will create a parent `div` when the string contains multiple elements](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html-fragments).

You can work with individual fragments instead:

```
from lxml import html
test_cases = ['<div>1</div><div>2</div>', 'I am pure text']
for test_case in test_cases:
    fragments = html.fragments_fromstring(test_case)
    print(fragments)
    output = ''
    for fragment in fragments:
        if isinstance(fragment, str):
            output += fragment
        else:
            output += html.tostring(fragment).decode('UTF-8')
    print(output)
```

output:

> ```
> [<Element div at 0x3403ea8>, <Element div at 0x3489368>]
> <div>1</div><div>2</div>
> ['I am pure text']
> I am pure text
> ```